# compare dates in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

So I have a date field in my database. Its of the type "Date". The value of the field is `2014-05-04` (yyyy-dd-mm).

How do I check, in sql, if the date is before or after today?

So far I have tied with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE theDate > GetDate()

SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(theDate as Date) > CAST(GetDate() as Date)
```

How do you check if "2014-05-04" is before today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointy bit of less than / greater than points to the lesser side.

So you want

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE theDate < convert(date, GetDate())
```

Comment: Does convert needed ? `(DECLARE @d DATE = '2010-04-01'

SELECT 1 WHERE @d< GETDATE())`

Comment: @RoyiNamir It depends whether you mean before today, or before now. This morning was before now, but not before today.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT(DATE, colDateTime)> CAST(GETTDATE() AS DATE)
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
TheDate,
CASE 
WHEN  TheDate < GETDATE() 
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS DateBeforeToday
FROM Table
```